# jquery datepicker time change

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datediff

Last days I was facing a strange behavior calculating date diff with jquery datepicker,
when I try to find out the difference in days of two dates crossing the 28th march. The difference, instead of returning an integer number as expected, gives me a float number slightly less than the integer expected.

I mean, the difference between `25th march` and `28th march` should be `3` days but it gives me `2.9583333333333335` days.

Whenever the 28th march is within the range I get this weird result.

I guess this is due to the time changing.
With any other range that problem doesn't fire.

I've found out how to solve this problem with some easy mathematics:

```
Math.floor((b-a)/(1000*60*60*24)+0.05);
```

Is it the time changing that leads to that weird result? Or is just my code?

here is some code (modification of a jquery date-picker [example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range)) which shows that:

http://jsfiddle.net/zKwbf/1/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has to be due to the time change.  If you multiply that decimal by 24 hours, you get 23.
What happens during the range when the hour goes back an hour in the fall

Comment: simple demonstration but efficacious! jquery datepicker is smarter than me! thanks